# Json Date to Java Date and back to Json Date

Tags: java, json, date

I looked through all possible answer here but I am having hard time to figure this thing out.

I have Json date in a String. I want to convert into a Java Date without losing time.

Also I would like to convert from Java Date to Json Date string.

Here what I have.

```
String jsonDateString = "/Date(1295157600000-0600)/";
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts in your time : the local time in milliseconds, and the offset in hours and minutes. You have to parse them and "add" them to get the milliseconds UTC.

You may do it using this function :

```
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)([+-]\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\)");
public static Date jd2d(String jsonDateString) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonDateString);
    if (m.find()) {
        long millis = Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
        long offsetHours = Long.parseLong(m.group(2));
        long offsetMinutes = Long.parseLong(m.group(3));
        if (offsetHours<0) offsetMinutes *= -1;
        return new Date(
            millis
            + offsetHours*60l*60l*1000l
            + offsetMinutes*60l*1000l
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

To make "back" a JSON date, I would simply encode the UTC time :

```
String jsonDate = "/Date("+date.getTime()+"+0000)/";
```

Comment: Did you try that with the sample string?

Comment: Not sure about the `-0600`?  That's the offset, a perfectly accepted part of what has unfortunately been called "JSON Dates".  Oh how I hate that term!  Why did this terrible format arise? What was wrong with ISO 8601 or just plain millis!  [OH THE HORROR! OH MY EYES!!](http://bit.ly/AgRj3r)

Comment: Thank you all. By using dystroy's suggestion I was able to convert to Long. I should have more clear on my questions. This json date I am getting from WCF REST service. Also I looked into "-0600" of the date and it is timezone offset. Since I am using dystroy's solution, is there a way I can keep the time zone information also?