# Rest API getAll() method give me date like this 1519561301000 instead of actual date

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-boot

I am writing an application in which I have a `Rest-API` which is `getAll()` method and I take date parameter also in this. But when I hit a `GET` request in **POSTMAN**, I see date coming as `1519561301000` instead of '`2018-02-25 20:10:29`' . Actual date is there in `Mysql DB`.

Is it a known thing or I am going in wrong direction?

In Response creationdate is like this:

```
"creationtimestamp": 1519569629000,
```

Any help would be appreciated..

I am using `SPRING_BOOT` `MysqlDB` and `POSTMAN` to check the responses.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been addressed multiple time already.

Comment: More duplicates/similar: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865455/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38567128/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18121082/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46298350/642706) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14316375/642706) and many others.

Comment: This is not same question. This is related to some json problem

Comment: I posted the json related solution here. this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041748/9445226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "JsonFormat" in your return object, try this:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date creationtimestamp;
```

See more about date format in:

[Docs Oracle - SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

And Read more about "JsonFormat":

[Jackson Annotations - JsonFormat](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html)

Comment: I went through the Jackson Annotations - JsonFormat page, It was indeed helpful. I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is likely (as the response property's name implies this) the Unix timestamp version of the date. This is defined as the number of seconds since the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

You should be able to easily convert this to any time format and timezone of your preference with Java's date related APIs.

Comment: Hi If I print the timestamp in spring boot I am getting the same timestamp as saved in DB but when I see the response in Postman It gives me in Epoch standard. Getting response in postman is same what I display on the UI from my angular 2 code. Hence On my UI (which is made from angular2) displays the time stamp in Epoch standard. Thats where I am failing to get the real timestamp

Comment: I will give a try to add some code for conversion in the angular side

Answer (score 1):

I think this solve your issue

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;    
import java.util.Date;    
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class TimestampToDateExample1 {    
       public static void main(String args[]){
            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(Long.parseLong("1519569629000"));  
            Date date = new Date(ts.getTime()); 
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
            String strDate = formatter.format(date);  
            System.out.println(strDate);                          
        }    
}
```

if you need to format date in javascript

```
let d = new Date(1519569629000 * 1000);
   let v =  ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
console.log(v);
```

may be its help you

Comment: Hi If I print the timestamp in spring boot I am getting the same timestamp as saved in DB but when I see the response in Postman It gives me in Epoch standard.
Getting response in postman is same what I display on the UI from my angular 2 code. Hence On my UI (which is made from angular2) displays the time stamp in Epoch  standard. Thats where I am failing to get the real timestamp.

Comment: I will give a try to add some code for conversion in the angular side.

Comment: please find the updated  answer may help you

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I was able to solve by adding @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "IST") annotation.