# Date type is getting converted to timestamp in postman JSON response, how to avoid that?

Tags: java, json, date, datetime, datetime-format

```
Java.util.Date
startDate : 2020-07-13 09:00:00.0
```

// JSON response

```
"startDate" : 1594611000000
```

I want to display in JSON as 2020-07-13 09:00:00.0

Comment: Your code would be helpful :)

Comment: You need to configure the serialization library (in the application server).

Comment: How are you producing your JSON? What library and configuration are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) and format the given date-time using [`DateTimeFormater#ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) as shown below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

        // Get Instant from the time-stamp of 1594611000000
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1594611000000L);

        // Get OffsetDateTime from instant
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30));

        // Get LocalDateTime from odt
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();

        // Get string in the defined format
        String dateTimeStr = formatter.format(ldt);

        // Display the formatted ldt
        System.out.println(dateTimeStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-13 09:00:00.0
```

**Note:** `LocalDateTime` drops the important information of time-zone and zone-offset from it. Choose the right date-time object from the [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) given below as per your requirement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the POJO object used for serialization/deserialization has a Date field, something like below, it should be informed to the library (say, Jackson ) which is used for serializing/deserializing.

```
class JsonTest{
  private Date date;
}
```

When the serialization/deserialization is performed, the details of the data format is to be set with the Serializer/ DeSerializer. Sample Deserialization code using Jackson (using com.fasterxml.jackson.core) can be

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, ParseException 

{
        //2020-07-13 09:00:00.0
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        String dateString = format.format( new Date()   );
        Date   date       = format.parse ( "2020-07-13 09:00:00.0" );
        JsonTest jsonTest = new JsonTest();
        jsonTest.setDate(date);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //mapper should know that the  specific format is needed while conversion 
        mapper.setDateFormat(format);
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonTest));

    }
```

The output will be printed as

```
{"date":"2020-07-13 09:00:00.0"}
```

Comment: I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) and format the given date-time using [`DateTimeFormater#ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) instead of using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand from your question so want to get the date in a particular format in the response body.

In java you can you can add the @JsonFormat annotation above your field in DTO class.
Change the pattern format as per your requirement.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date startDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

You mention that your variable startDate is of Date type, now i don't know what language you are using but i can try an educated guess of what you need to do :

Format you Date type in order to have a String type and put that String in your JSON. Being a String and not the interpretation of a Timestamp, is shouldn't be converted.